# Zeppelin crashes with TTransportException in Spark MLlib GBT

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-zeppelin

I am playing with Zeppelin and Spark MLlib, everything installed on VirtualBox (Win 10 host/Linux guest).

In general I enjoy it, but there is 1 situation when Zeppelin consistently crashes with **org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException**. This happens when I am trying to use gradient-boosted tree regression from a new MLlib API.

It always crashes after several minutes of work.

It never crashes in other situations. E.g. I ran cross-validation for a complex linear regression and it took almost 30 hours of full CPU load without any problems. If I set a small number of iterations for GBT, so that it can be completed in 1-2 mins then it also works fine.

1) Any ideas why it may not work with GBT longer than a couple of minutes?

2) Where to look for a root cause?

I use Spark 2.0.2 and Zeppelin 0.6.2.